# Javascript Dojo development script error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, dojo

An interesting problem about dojo toolkit and javasacript. 
I am using a visual studio to developing application

I have created a module as following and named its file as calc.js

**djConfig.js**

```
var pathRegex = new RegExp(/\/[^\/]+$/);
var locationPath = location.pathname.replace(pathRegex, '');
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [
    {
        name: 'application',
        location: locationPath + '/js/application'
    }
};
```

**calc.js**

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
 return  declare(null, {
    Sum: function(x,y) {
        return x + y; 
    }
 }); })
```

Once created this file I references this file in index.html file as following,
**index.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/application/djConfig.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    require(["application/calc"],
        function(calc) {
            var c = new calc();
            console.log(c.Sum(1, 2));
        }
    );
</script>
```

This code is wirking at first.Calculating sum and writing in concole of browser.
But than I am changing something in calc.js (ex. return x+y-1;). 
The browser is giving a script error.
[image]
If I change something in index.html page - for example type a whitespace- than script is working.
[image]
All changes in calc.js file is throwing script error, if I do not change somewhere in index.html
Even If I type a whitespace or add a line in index page, every thing is working.

Did you encounter a problem like this?

Comment: return  declare(null,...  should be return  declare("application/calc"

Comment: Make sure your browser is picking up the latest versions of all changed files. Make sure the browser is loading your JS module by checking the `Network` panel. As a rule, constructor functions should start with uppercase - so `calc` should be `Calc`; and methods should start with lowercase, so `Sum` should be `sum`.

Comment: I think this is a browser or cache problem. When I use internet explorer, my changed code is throwing error as old code. How can I pick up latest versions of all changed files?

Comment: Add this to your page header (during development only) : <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE">

Comment: I inserted in html this tag <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE">: But not worked. When I run my project on visual studio, it is working on development server http://localhost:6002/. Is this a problem? If I create a Web Site project on IIS (http://localhost/myProj) not problem.

Comment: I updated my post with config file content. I think the problem is occuring config file regular expression location path. "http://localhost:6002" is throwing script error, But "ttp://localhost:6002/" or http://localhost:6002/index.html is working always well.

Comment: I work in a similar environment and whenever I change a class that is loaded by dojo, I have to close and re-open IE (our only authorized browser) in order for it to pick up the changes.  I also needed to set IE in Tools->General->Browsing History, Settings to check for new files whenever IE starts.  This has worked for me.